# Lumen return only fields specified in request

Tags: api, lumen

Usually I use [Yii2](https://www.yiiframework.com/) to build rest API's. Right now I'm trying to rebuild an API, that I already have in Yii2, with Lumen for studies pourposes.

For example:
I have an ModelA that have 5 fields:
field1, field2, field3, field4, field5

In Yii I can make a request like:
http://localhost:8000/modela/15

to get the modelA with ID 15. In Lumen I can do the same, that's ok.

In Yii, when I want to get just two field from that model I can make a request like:
http://localhost:8000/modela/15&fields=field1,field3

Does Lumen support something like that or would I have to build such feature from scratch?

Comment: your question is about laravel or Yii?

Comment: Lumen. "Does Lumen support something like that or would I have to build such feature from scratch?"